# glGenVertexArray crash my program

Tags: opengl, c++

Hi I started today to make an OpenGL program, I made the shader class, mesh class and texture class. When I tried to test it, it stopped working. After a little debug with Visual Studio(thanks Microsoft for this useful tool). It showed me that my problem is:

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_vao);
```

I use glew. I searched on internet, and I found that glewExperimental needs to be GL_TRUE, so I init it like this:

```
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
GLenum error = glewInit();
if (error != GLEW_OK)
    std::cerr << "Glew: " << glewGetErrorString(error);
```

nothing changed.

Error given by Visual Studio:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in DirtyCraft.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000. occurred
```

I do use Glew 2.0.0, 32-bits, SDL2.

If you need any additional information, feel free to request them.

Comment: (1) what graphics hardware have you? (2) did you call glewInit before or after creating your GL context?

Comment: I have a gtx 950, and glewInit is called after context creation, it's the last part of the window constructor

Comment: Thanks. Are you able to create shaders and buffers or do you crash on those too? Rearrange some code if necessary. Right now it seems as though you're not getting a hardware-accelerated GL context.

Comment: I'm not at my pc, but it could be a problem of linking?

Comment: Btw, shaders works, not tested them, but I saw compile errors.

Comment: It does give me the same error, for every function that gl.h or glu.h doesnt have, I had tested it

Comment: OK, so you're definitely not getting a hardware accelerated context.  Download the OpenGL extensions viewer from http://realtech-vr.com/admin/glview and check the "system Info" and "OpenGL" sections on the main screen of it.

Answer (score 1):

The Window that holds the rendering must be opened first. Also, you need to call glew first before calling any opengl functions.

Comment: thank you, but I solved. Somehow glDrawElements was messing up something in glew, so I reinstalled glew